# Organizing graphics, icons and photos

Tags: asset-management

I'm a UX developer and have 1000s of icons, ui designs and ui parts and the like and would like to better organize them. Currently I have them in well marked folders such as:

- icons-currency
- icons-globes
- ui-forms
- ui-navigation-tabs
- ui-scrollbars

I'm not happy with this method and am leaning more towards tagging individual graphics as opposed to putting into different directories. I think tagging will allow me to more easily "cross-pollinate" different ideas (meaning that I things won't be so rigidly separated).

In case it matters I work with Windows (as I suppose you got from my use of directories instead of folders).

I've looked at Adobe Bridge and it seems close to what I'm thinking about. Ideally I would like to be able to work on an icon or idea and keep it in the project working directory and tag it so I can find it easily later.

How do you keep your 1000s of icons, completed projects and ideas organized?

**EDIT:**

I have no problem finding things when I'm looking for something I know. Example: looking for scrollbars I go to UX-Scrollbars. (no problem)

But there are many times I'm looking for something less clear than a specific UX attribute, something that (1) I can barely picture in my mind; or (2)something that was part of a screenshot and saved elsewhere.

I will look more at Windows tagging. When I tried it a while back the "tag" wasn't automatically part of the search box.

**EDIT 2:**

WOW - I played with tags a while ago and didn't find as useful as I wanted. This seems to work well in addition to folders. It's not as user friendly as I would want ... but too bad. It works. The one last thing I will have to check is to see if the tags stay with the file as I move them to another computer.

The tags do stay with the file. It works! Ugly, but works.

**EDIT 3:**

As a follow-up tagging does not work on .gifs or .pngs.

> You cannot store tags to .GIF files because metadata was not included in the standard for the CompuServe Graphics Interchange Format. You could theoretically store tags to .PNG files because a lot of versatility was written into the Portable Network Graphics format, but to date no single standard for storing metadata to PNGs has arisen.   http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/tagging-png-and-gif-files/67f74612-3ea0-4d59-a0b8-dfbc648805fd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do:

Use lots and lots of subfolders.

It's a little cumbersome to navigate to, but instead of just using one folder for about 5 sub-categories, place folders within folders like this:

UI> Forms UI> Navigation> Tabs UI> Scrollbars>scrollbar.png

Also, it is dramatically easier to find files if you use tags. I assume you didn't notice this, neither did I until I looked it up. Here's a little tutorial:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/tag-your-files-for-easier-searches-in-windows-7/

If you are using Windows 8, tags are a lot better because the built in search is way faster than 7. If you use lots of tags, this process is really great.

If you really want to use a 3rd party file manager, you can go with Bridge, but I find it hard to recommend unless you need something really powerful.